# Direct link to create news page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have custom menu with an option to "create news page". It links to the news site only, and the user are forced to click "new" and then "news post" as seen in the attached picture. Is it possible to get the link (or in any other way) to the "news post" function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is 3 years old and you probably got your solution. But in case someone stumbles upon it:

This is the URL structure you are looking for:

```
https://**tennant**.sharepoint.com/sites/**Site**/_layouts/15/CreatePageFromTemplate.aspx?source=/sites/**Site**/_layouts/15/news.aspx?newsSource=**x**&instanceId=**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**&webPartId=**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**&serverRelativeUrl=/sites/**Site**&pagesListId=**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**&promotedState=1
```

Good news are that you don't have to figure out all those IDs manually - go to your news webpart and click on "Show All" to go to the news overview page. You will notice that URL in your browser has taken all those IDs as parameters over. Copy those and edit the url to match the template above, don't forget the "PromotedState=1" at the end.

For a normal page only the first part will suffice:

https://**tennant**.sharepoint.com/sites/**Site**/_layouts/15/CreatePageFromTemplate.aspx